# Leaflet Polyline is not being drawn entirely when panning

Tags: leaflet, polyline

I've added a polyline on a leafletjs map. However, after I zoom in far enough for the view bounds to only show some of the polyline and I drag away towards the other side of the polyline while holding the mouse button down, the polyline is not being drawn while the new side of the map renders, but only after I release the mouse.

Is there any way to bypass this default behavior?

An example of my situation can be found [here](https://harrywood.co.uk/maps/examples/leaflet/polyline.view.html).

Leaflet polyline - https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#polyline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This Leaftet Github issue](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/2814) is relevant - you can add an invisible margin outside the bounds of the map in which the polyline will render and will appear when you drag back.

Like this:

```
var map = new L.Map('map');
map.getRenderer(map).options.padding = 100;
```